# JS command() API is not displaying more than 2 lines of messages for WPF solution with CEFSharp V84

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJIXE.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>HTML DOM Events</h1>
<h2>The onclick Event</h2>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Confirm</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
        var message = "You have selected:";
        message += "Stmt1 \r\n stmt2 \r\n stmt2";
        message += "\r\n";
        message += "stmt2stmt2stmt2stmt2stmt2stmt2stmt2stmt2stmt2stmt2stmt2\n";
        message += "stmt2stmt2stmt2stmt2stmt2stmt2stmt2stmt2stmt2stmt2stmt2stmt2";
        status = confirm(message);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here after 3rd line of the message , it is hidden.Also window size is not increasing to contain full text.  Same is working fine with IE.

Comment: [link]https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJIXE.png  this is image for the same.

Comment: Why would you use confirm dialog in the first place?

Comment: This is a known limitation of the default CEF implementation and should be fixed in the next couple of versions. You can implement your own custom dialog as a workaround, via IJsDialogHandler https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#handlers

Comment: I'll see if I have time to provide a more detailed example later.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace CefSharp.Wpf.Example.Handlers
{
    public class JsDialogHandler : CefSharp.Handler.JsDialogHandler
    {
        protected override bool OnJSDialog(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, CefJsDialogType dialogType, string messageText, string defaultPromptText, IJsDialogCallback callback, ref bool suppressMessage)
        {
            var b = (ChromiumWebBrowser)chromiumWebBrowser;

            b.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                if (dialogType == CefJsDialogType.Confirm)
                {
                    var messageBoxResult = MessageBox.Show(messageText, $"A page at {originUrl} says:", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);

                    callback.Continue(messageBoxResult == MessageBoxResult.Yes);
                }
                else if(dialogType == CefJsDialogType.Alert)
                {
                    var messageBoxResult = MessageBox.Show(messageText, $"A page at {originUrl} says:", MessageBoxButton.OK);

                    callback.Continue(messageBoxResult == MessageBoxResult.OK);
                }
                else if (dialogType == CefJsDialogType.Prompt)
                {
                    var messageBoxResult = PromptDialog.Prompt(messageText, $"A page at {originUrl} says:", defaultPromptText);

                    callback.Continue(messageBoxResult.Item1, userInput: messageBoxResult.Item2);
                }
            });

            return true;
        }
    }
}

//Assign your handler to the ChromiumWebBrowser instance
browser.JsDialogHandler = new CefSharp.Wpf.Example.Handlers.JsDialogHandler();
```

Full example added in commit https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/df8a6086a6bbb79280916c955015a1b58a421ddc